# How to remove pizza pan from oven without a peel?

Tags: baking, pizza

I was given a set of mini-pizza pans for making personal sized pizzas, but I noticed these pans don't have handles or ridges around the edge like my larger pizza pan to grip with my oven mitt. I don't have a pizza peel, so I'm wondering what the best alternative method for getting the pizza out of the oven with equipment I probably already have around the kitchen?

Comment: I wouldn't use a pizza peel anyway, it may not take the weight and it's too slippery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a spatula or tongs to pull pizzas off of a pizza pan/stone in the oven onto an upside down baking sheet, cutting board, or even a plate, assuming your pans are just flat surfaces, like a pizza stone.

You can also assemble pizzas on the upside down baking pan and slide them off it onto the stone in the oven.

Answer (score 1):

If you are cooking on the pizza pan, you can simply grab the edge with tongs and slide it over the front of the rack onto a larger pan or plate.